# Tampermonkey script that will close tab if page have this element in code

Tags: tampermonkey

I have a page with columns and I need to close the tab if the first column has this src="imgs/newmail.gif"

I will send you a screenshot of part of the code.
[`<tr> <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">1</td> <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"> <img src="imgs/newmail.gif" border="0">                  </td>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfJQt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad you haven't given us much to work with, and the below script is untested, but try this as a starting point:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Close Tab if Img Found
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @grant        window.close
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

    setTimeout(() => {
        //allow a few ms for page to fully load
        if ( $('img[src=imgs/newmail.gif"]') !== undefined && $('img[src=imgs/newmail.gif"]') !== null){
            window.close();
        }
    });
})();
```

You will need to change the `//match` line, and you might have to tweak the line that watches for the correct image tag.

Give us more information and we can try to tweak it a little more for you.

PS - The above code is not jQuery - look carefully.

Reference:

https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant

Comment: If I did everything right, it probably won't work.
This was my first post on the site, so I apologize for not providing more information.
Please tell me what other information I need to prepare in order to disclose my problem?

Comment: Okay, I tweaked the code a bit (and removed a library requirement that should not have been there, don't know what I was thinking).  Please try again. IF it doesn't work this time, then we need to be sure that the script is triggering.  Add `alert("hello") before the line `window.close()` and report back.